# Filter an array of objects and extract its property by using an array of keys

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, dictionary, filter

im having this problem which i cant wrap around my head,

much better if put in a code.

```
//Array of objects sample
var objects = [{id:1, name:'test1'}, {id:2, name:'test2'}, {id:3, name: 'test3'}, {id:4, name:'test4'}];
var arrayOfKeys = [3,1,4];

//extract object name property if its id property is equivalent to one of arrayOfKeys [3,1] 
//var arrayOfKeys = [3,1,4];
//output sample: extractedName=['test3','test1','test4'];
```

i've been using filter and map but no avail, also tried nesting filter inside map im getting an arrays of array and inside is a single object.

Comment: I dont understand exactly what do you want

Comment: Are the names always going to be `testN` where `N` is a number?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir yes, its continuous, even i add another id to arrayOfKeys it should still correspond to the id property of the object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could map the objects and ren map the wanted keys for getting the name.

```js
var objects = [{ id: 1, name: 'test1' }, { id: 2, name: 'test2' }, { id: 3, name: 'test3' }],
    arrayOfKeys = [3, 1],
    result = arrayOfKeys.map((map => id => map.get(id).name)(new Map(objects.map(o => [o.id, o]))));
    
console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice and concise!

Comment: @Andreas I am going to have to disagree. Her answers always super efficient and I am always learning something new from her code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you need to map array numbers to `id` properties? Here's the code where you `map` through numbers and `find` inside your array to handle situations when there's no such `id` in objects array:

```js
var objects = [{id:1, name:'test1'}, {id:2, name:'test2'}, {id:3, name: 'test3'}];
var arrayOfKeys = [3,1];

var res = arrayOfKeys.map(key => {
  var found = objects.find(o => o.id == key);
  return found ? found.name : false;
})

console.log(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
let objects = [{id:1, name:'test1'}, {id:2, name:'test2'}, {id:3, name: 'test3'}, {id:4, name:'test4'}],
    arrayOfKeys = [3,1,4];

let result = objects.reduce((res, obj) => {    // loop over the array of objects
  let index = arrayOfKeys.indexOf(obj.id);     // check if the current object's id is in the array of keys
  if(index !== -1) {                           // if it's there
    res.push(obj.name);                        // then add the current object's name to the result array
    arrayOfKeys.splice(index, 1);              // remove its id from the array of keys so we won't search for it again (optional, slightly better than leaving it there)
  }
  return res;
}, []);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you were on the right track with the filter. You can make it readable and concise with some.

```js
var objects = [{id: 1,name: 'test1'}, {id: 2,name: 'test2'}, {id: 3,name: 'test3'}, {id: 4,name: 'test4'}],
arrayOfKeys = [3, 1, 4];

var result = objects.filter((x, i) => {
  if (arrayOfKeys.some(k => x.id === k)) {
    return true;
  }
})
console.log(result.map(x=>x.name));
```

Something even shorter! would be

```js
var objects = [{id: 1,name: 'test1'}, {id: 2,name: 'test2'}, {id: 3,name: 'test3'}, {id: 4,name: 'test4'}],arrayOfKeys = [3, 1, 4];

var result = objects.filter((x, i) => arrayOfKeys.some(k => x.id === k));

console.log(result.map(x=>x.name));
```